# Return multiple columns from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, cross-join

### WHAT I WANT

I have 2 tables :

1. `_order`, which contains column `_order_id` (`_order_id` varies from 25 to 62, i.e., 38 records)
2. `payment` which contains column `paym_id` (`paym_id` varies from 1 to 38, i.e., 38 records)

I want to return a table which contains 2 columns :

1. `_order_id` (from `_order` table)
2. `paym_id` (from `payment` table)

with all the 38 records.

**FYI** : Tables `_order` and `payment` are not related by any foreign key.

---

### WHAT I TRIED & THE PROBLEM

I ran the following query :

**Query # 1**)

```
    SELECT _order._order_id, payment.paym_id
    FROM
    _order, payment
    LIMIT 0,38
```

*Problem with query # 1* : Values of `_order_id` varies from 25 to 62 as expected, but, values of `paym_id` field remains the same for all rows, i.e., 1 (starting value)

Upon switching the sequence of `_order` and `payment` i.e., :

```
    SELECT _order._order_id, payment.paym_id
    FROM
    payment, _order
    LIMIT 0,38
```

values of `paym_id` varies from 1 to 38 as expected, but, values of `_order_id` field remains the same for all rows, i.e., 25 (starting value)

**Query # 2**)

```
    SELECT _order._order_id, payment.paym_id
    FROM
    _order CROSS JOIN payment
    LIMIT 0,38
```

*Problem with query # 2* : Same as problem with Query # 1

---

### Looking for some help. Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT : Query # 2 was actually a CROSS JOIN operation. My bad.**

Comment: If you don't have a foreign key between `order` and `payment`, how do you expect to relate them to each other? You can't rely on the order of rows coming out of either table being the same every time.

Comment: @Nick. Query # 2 was actually a CROSS JOIN operation which behaves the same as Query # 1. In Query # 2 "FROM _order CROSS JOIN payment", field of latter (payment) i.e., paym_id remains constant for all rows. Whereas, if sequence of _order and payment is changed i.e., "FROM payment CROSS JOIN _order", field of latter (_order) i.e., _order_id remains constant for all rows. The problem in general is that for a query "SELECT a.a_id, b.b_id FROM a CROSS JOIN b", since b is latter, i.e., "FROM a CROSS JOIN b", in the rows returned fields of b i.e., "b.b_id" remains constant for all rows.